# How can I know who voted to close a question of mine?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

How can I know the three people who voted to close a question of mine **before** the number of five votes is reached, and when they voted so?

Comment: Not 100% sure (so not an answer), but I've never found a way so I think 'you can't'.

Comment: Why do you want to know that? Didn't someone leave a comment for possible reasons _why_ the question may be closed? (That's IMHO the more interesting question than _who_ voted...)

Comment: @cgnieder as you can see (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119800/is-it-still-useful-disabling-write18-in-the-era-of-luatex?noredirect=1#comment267214_119800) there are 3 closing proposals and no comments. I'm just a bit curious.

Comment: They all are for “Not a real question” (“It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.”), probably because the answer to the question seems to be “because the developers decided so”

Comment: We can close the question if you really want to find out, reopen it. But I agree that the question is a little tooambiguous. You ask a) whether \write18 is relevant, b) Why Lua is running Lua scripts freely c) Python part and other implications. There are a few  similar questions about safety on the main site too.

Comment: @percusse What I ask is that given by the title ('Is still useful ...') and I think is not ambiguous. But this is a tiny problem as far as I indicated that thread only as an example. The title of *this* question is unambiguous too: 'How can I know who voted ...'. The sense is that the interface of the forum is lacking of the possibility to know who is proposing to close a given question. I propose: 1) modify the interface of the forum, and/or 2) set as a rule that who vote for the closing of a question is obliged to give an explanation in the comments of the question itself.

Comment: @JeanBaldraque I still don't get why it would matter at all _who_ voted?

Comment: @JeanBaldraque The title of the question is not inline with the text. The sentences are by themselves OK. Not together